# Joomla 1.5 user group creation and access level

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 1.5. For my website, I want to create custom groups in backend and assign user to that group so that they get access to only some part of sections in administrator.

I have created a new group as "Account Department" under "Manager" group of "Public Back-end". But when I assign any user to "Account Department" group that user is unable to login into the administrator. I want to create multiple such groups having different backend access.

Please suggest the solution for the same ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you added a group, but there is a lot more to it than just adding a row in the table.  The whole point of 1.6-2.5 was ACL, if you can't migrate find a 1.5 extensio that provides acl, there were at least 4-5 available.